Riemannian Langevin dynamics choice of metric?
This paper https://arxiv.org/pdf/1506.04696 introduces a general framework for (stochastic) Riemannian Langevine dynamics by showing how to construct an SDE with desired stationary distribution with a general position dependent PSD matrix $D(z)$ and skew-symmetric curl matrix $Q(z)$.
In the appendix they mention that an interesting choice for $D(z)$ is the Fisher-Information matrix. However, that only seems to be applicable in a bayesian inference setting, so if we want to sample from $p(x|y)$, then we can form a Fisher-Information matrix by calculating $E_{p(y|x)}[\nabla_x \log p(y|x) \nabla_x \log p(y|x) ^\top]$
However, what is a good metric in the simpler setting where I only have $p(x)$ I want to sample from, no $y$? In that setting the expectation to calculate the Fisher information matrix doesnt make sense, or am i missing something?
I thought about the Hessian of $p(x)$ or of $-\log{(p(x))}$ but that is not guaranteed to be PSD. Is there something better, or can I use one of the tricks from the optimization literature to make the Hessian PSD?
